# How to bypass JS Uncaught Typeerror when Element in not available

Tags: javascript, dom

Take this simple function:

```
$ = function(expr, con) {
    return typeof expr === "string"? (con || document).querySelector(expr) : expr || null;
}
```

Works great if the element is available in the DOM. If not, you get a Typeerror and JS parsing stops. 
I don't want to check every Element if it exists:

```
if($("elem")) $("elem").innerHTML = "...";
```

I just want to call

```
$("elem").innerHTML = "...";
```

without getting an error when the Element is not available.

Comment: You could catch the error and return an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i think you can do:

```js
$ = function(expr, con) {
    var el = typeof expr === "string"? (con || document).querySelector(expr) : expr || null;
    return el || document.createElement("div");
}


$("elem").innerHTML = "...";
```

with that you won't get any errors, because if your element is not available the function will return a *ghost element* instead

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak the if / else.

```
$ = function(expr, con) {
    return typeof expr === "string"? ((con || document).querySelector(expr) || {}) : expr;
}
```